# PHP dns_get_record rate limit?

Tags: php, dns

I frame this question within PHP/dns_get_record context, although it applies to other languages/API's as well:

**How often can one call dns_get_record to query the DNS for records?**

My common sense tells me that there should be some sort of limit implemented on the DNS side to protect themselves, and I wonder what the limit is like in the practical world.

I am implementing a cron job to fetch latest DNS records for domains stored in my DB. The job runs maybe once a day or so. Potentially I can have thousands of domains. Therefore, if I put all these domains into a cron job, it's likely some of my requests can be denied by DNS. Or even worse, I can be blacklisted by DNS because they might think I am attacking them.

If I know the rate limit imposed by DNS, I can spread the requests more evenly to play nicely with DNS.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the DNS server, there's no standard limit.

Comment: You could always run your own DNS server for this. Setting up a caching-only DNS server is trivial.

Comment: But still, the DNS server needs to update itself from the outside world once a day. I am not sure if that avoids the issue.

Comment: This avoids the issue because you won't be sending to the same external DNS server for every request. You'll send to your own DNS server, which has no rate limit, and the recursive requests will be spread over many different authoritative servers.

Comment: I see. Thanks for this idea!

Comment: alternatively you could look at one of the many dns API's

Comment: What volume are you talking about? It is improbable so you will hit problems (thousands of query is nothing). While rate limiting do exist as they are bad actors, it would probably not be your case. As for " DNS server needs to update itself from the outside world once a day." this is completely **NOT** how the DNS works! A recursive caching nameserver will get data and cache it in continuous matter...

Comment: I am talking about potentially thousands requests within a second, burst.